# how to disable all keyboards on my computers

Tags: powershell

I want to disable the keyboard on my pc so I used this code:

```powershell
get-pnpdevice | where-object {$_.FriendlyName -match 'HID Keyboard Device'} |disable-pnpdevice
```

But I get this error:

```plaintext
**disable-pnpdevice : Generic failure**
```

If I run this code:

```powershell
get-pnpdevice | where-object {$_.FriendlyName -match 'HID-compliant mouse'} | DISABLE-PNPDEVICE
```

I get an error but the mouse is disabled on my computer. I ran PowerShell as administrator. What could be the problem that the keyboard does not disconnect?

Comment: Are you sure the keyboard device is named `HID Keyboard Device` ?

Comment: Even if you had `-PassThru` as an argument for `Disable-PnpDevice` ?

Comment: i sure the keyboard is this name. i search all keyboard in Class.

Comment: Kluk - I don't understand what to do

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have more than 1 keyboard device recognized by your computer, and one of them is not able to be disabled (disallowed by the OS for some reason). And the failure is causing the pipe to fail the entire set.

I would recommend trying one of these to see if they help...

```powershell
Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName 'HID Keyboard Device' | Disable-PnpDevice -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Or

```powershell
Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName 'HID Keyboard Device' | % { Disable-PnpDevice -InputObject $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue )
```

---

My thinking is that if you have 3 keyboard devices found by `Get-PnpDevice` and you are trying to disable them via piping to `Disable-PnpDevice`, if the first one fails to disable, it could exit the whole loop, preventing the other two from being disabled.

By using `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` you are telling it to ingore any errors. Though I will admit, I don't know without testing whether it will ignore the error for a single execution within the loop, or if it will simply ignore the failure of the whole command.

This is why I provided a second option to try running the disables individually, and ignore the errors of them.

Comment: i have 1 keyborad on my computer. 
I tried it but it did not work.

Comment: I only have 1 keyboard on my computer as well, but the `Get-PnpDevice` command returns 3 keyboards as there are probably some virtual keyboards or devices with keyboard capabilities.

Comment: the Get-PnpDevice returns me 9 keyboards but the  status of 8 of them is Unknown.